# Getting currentfeature's color in Expression Builder of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, color, expression

In QGIS Expression builder. I want to obtain the color code of the current feature.

I mean:

My layer contains lines, each one is painted with a different color. Now I want to assign that color to its label. In label definition, in the color property's expressions builder, how could I obtain that attribute?

I tried:

attribute( $currentfeature, 'color')

But it is not working...

Comment: by the way I am using QGIS 2.8.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In QGIS >= 2.14 you can use the symbol_color variable. Eg, set a data defined override for your label color to the expression `@symbol_color`

Comment: not working with 3.16

Answer (score 9):

Can it be done. Of couse with QGIS the answer is normally yes.

Lets take our vector layer with some normal labels and symbols:

[image]

Now add a data defined color for the buffer:

[image]

Click on Edit and select the function editor.

[image]

Click new file and give it a name (called mine colorfuncs)

Paste the following code

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def symbol_color(layername, feature, parent):
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)[0]
    r = layer.rendererV2()
    symbol = r.symbolForFeature(feature)
    values = symbol.color().getRgb()
    return "{}, {}, {}, {}".format(*values)
```

Should look like this:

[image]

Hit **Run Script**

Jump back over to the expressions tab and use the new function:

```
symbol_color('Pits')
```

We have to give it the name because expressions don't know about the layer only the feature.

Hit OK and Apply. BAM!

[image]

hmm almost.  We just have to tweak the transparecny of the buffer:

[image]

BAM!

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Nathan W very useful your script. What is 'Pits' in you example?

Comment: The layer name of the layer you are styling.

Comment: mmm QGIS gets stuck when i type the last character of the layer. In my case symbol_color('itineraries'). When I type the last s QGIS crashes and closes...