# QGIS Color text labels the same color as the feature

Tags: qgis, labeling, ubuntu, color, expression

Using QGIS 2.12.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop. 
What I have is a layer where each feature is a different color. I also want to label each feature but I want the label colors to match the feature colors. I tried [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152208/66068) to [Getting currentfeature's color in Expression Builder of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/152203/115) but as mentioned by one of the commenters I am also getting QGIS to crash when I try to apply that symbol_color function.

I tried asking in the QGIS irc channel on #freenode but nobody seems to be responding.